# Where does bash's 'help' builtin source its documentation?

Tags: bash, man, signals, documentation

On MacOS, the default bash on the OS is 3.2.

If I run `help trap` it says that if the signal_spec is DEBUG, that the command is run *after* each command, but the bash manpage says it is run *before* each command.  The actual behavior of this bash agrees with the manpage (i.e. *before* the command).

I downloaded the source of 4.4.18(1) and built it.  Both the manpage and `help trap` say that the trap is executed *before* each command.  However, even then, the text of each of those pieces of documentation are slightly different.

So my naive assumption that the `help` builtin reads/parses the manpage is clearly incorrect.

So where does `help` get its info that it relays to the user?

Comment: Internal bash structures.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, it's baked into the executable after a few levels of source generation.

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/trap.def?id=b0776d8c49ab4310fa056ce1033985996c5b9807#n25

So the various builtin definition files have the documentation in them which gets converted into `builtins.c` by `mkbuiltins`.

I guess the MacOS bash manpages were updated to reflect the correct behavior of trap in with a DEBUG signal_spec whereas the definition source was not updated and the executable rebuilt.